# HTML special characters in CSS "content" attribute

Tags: css, xhtml, character

I'm trying to add content to something before an item using the CSS :before + content: fields. I want to insert a checkmark (☑), BUT if I use that in the content option, it prints as the literal. How can I tell CSS to make that a checkmark, not the literal string ☑?

Comment: The question formulation is obscure. It was probably meant to refer to notations like `&#9745;` getting displayed literally (the explanation being that they have no special meaning in CSS), i.e. an attempt was made to use HTML “escapes” for characters in CSS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
#target:before {
  content: "\2611";
}
```

Comment: yes, but not exactly. That works (how did you know that??), but i need the checkbox with the box (&# 9745;), not just the checkmark. Where can I look up these alternative codes?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! May I ask where you are finding this information? Could you please cite a source for my future reference?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unicode_characters and thousands more pages.

Comment: Genius with the backslash!!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) values inside the `content` property. (The [list of miscellaneous symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols) may also be useful.)

A heavy checkmark is listed as `U+2713` so you would put `content: "\2713";`

Comment: +1 I was confused with an alternate symbol because I didn't realize the U+ translated into \, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the checkbox character literally in your CSS rule instead of the encoding -

```
#target:before {
    content: "☑";
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/e3Wt2/

Comment: This requires that the character encoding of the CSS file, or the HTML file containing CSS code, has been properly declared, see http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Did you check your encoding?

Comment: Just as importantly, it requires that the browser respect the coding; not all do. (I'm looking at older IE, of course.)