# Allowed characters in CSS 'content' property?

Tags: unicode, css

[I've read that](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) we must use [Unicode values inside the `content` CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4476362/1071413) i.e. `\` followed by the special character's hexadecimal number.

But what characters, other than alphanumerics, are actually allowed to be placed as is in the value of `content` property? (Google has no clue, hence the question.)

Comment: Check out these charts for availability; http://www.unicode.org/charts/ Keep in mind that controls (reserved codes) probably won't do anything, or either make the output and/or CSS invalid.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can basis alpha-numeric just "as is". For special HTML characters like `<` (`003C`) you would want to go for the Unicode variant.

Comment: @Allendar Yes, I know that, just wanted to know, as something I tried wasn't working earlier (but is working now -- weird). Thanks for the suggestion by the way. Appreciate!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules for “escaping” characters are in the CSS 2.1 specification, clause 4.1.3 [Characters and case](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters). The special rules for quoted strings, as in `content` property value, are in clause 4.3.7 [Strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings). Within a quoted string, any character may appear as such, except for the character used to quote the string (`"` or `'`), a newline character, or a backslash character `\`.

The information that you *must* use `\` escapes is thus wrong. You *may* use them, and may even need to use them if the character encoding of the document containing the style sheet does not let you enter all characters directly. But if the encoding is UTF-8, and is properly [declared](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset), then you can write `content: '☺ Я Ω ⁴ ®'`.

Comment: Unfortunately these can cause weird render issues in Chrome. Things like first render of the site has broken CSS, then a refresh helps...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can insert any Unicode character. ([Here's a useful list of Unicode characters and their codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).)

To utilize these codes, you must escape them, like so:

```
U+27BA Becomes \27BA
```

Or, alternatively, I think you may just be able to escape the character itself:

```
content: '\➺';
```

**Source:** http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I want to be sure of this.

Comment: Best way to find out is to check :)

Comment: For example, `content: \➺;` is not valid, as you can quickly check with the W3C CSS Validator. Quotes are missing, and the `\` does not help here, or do any good.