# How should I enter a Unicode character in CSS now that octal escapes are deprecated?

Tags: javascript, css, escaping, strict

I am adding CSS styles using JavaScript (specifically with GreaseMonkey's `GM_addStyle`).

I'd like to put a Unicode character in a CSS property.  I've seen a lot of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476322/html-special-characters-in-css-content-attribute) and the answer always seems to be along the lines of

```
#target:before {
    content: "\2611";
}
```

Now, as I said, this style is being specified in `GM_addStyle`, and the calling function has Strict mode enabled.  When my script runs, I get an error on the console with the message `octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated`.

I think the conflict here is between doing the operation in JavaScript (i.e. putting a Unicode character into a JavaScript string) and the operation in CSS (escaping the character when declaring a CSS property).  What syntax should I use to have the character escaped without generating an error?

Comment: Your question is confusing - are you referring to JavaScript, or CSS, or both? As far as I know, escape sequences in CSS have never been deprecated by any specification.

Comment: I think my confusion was the root issue.  I'm adding CSS style definitions with `GM_addStyle`; under the hood I think this is effectively writing new `<style>` tags using JavaScript.  So, the hex/octal -> Unicode character translation is actually happening when the JavaScript string is interpreted.  That's why Paul's answer is correct.

Comment: CSS never had “octal escape sequences”. There is real problem involved here, but it seems to be related to JavaScript, not to CSS at all. I’m afraid it has been expressed so confusingly that the question will hardly be useful to future visitors.

Comment: I think you are right, Jukka; I will add a postscript to try to clarify.

Comment: Also, in case anybody missed it in my comment below, I wanted to raise the visibility of [this article on JavaScript string escapes](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) which really helped to straighten me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to do just this in GreaseMonkey, with Strict mode enabled.

If you're going via *JavaScript*, then the *String* `'\2611'` doesn't have the same meaning as you think it does and you probably want the *String* `'\u2611'` or `'\\2611'`

```
'\2611';  // "±1"
'\u2611'; // "☑"
'\\2611'; // "\2611"
```

Comment: FWIW, the first is equivalent to `\u00b11`, i.e. the Unicode character `00b1` and a `"1"`

Comment: @lc. yep, for anyone interested in how to convert the first output as it's not a simple oct -> hex `'\261'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); // "b1"` then make this 4 digits long by prepending `"0"`s

Comment: While you were posting this, I was reading [an excellent article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) that explained the difference.  It makes a lot more sense now.  Thanks!